# Loop through unix array and get the last character and append string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, character

In the fruitlist array i need to loop through and print as I like apple(s), I like tomato(es)
the last letter should be captured and based on it i should append (s) or (es).  i couldnt get the last value this way.

when i tried echo $fn | tail -c 2 , it gives the last value but here it doesnt.

i must be missing something.

```
#!/bin/sh
fruitlist="apple pear tomato peach grape";
last="";
append="";
for fn in $fruitlist
do
last=$fn | tail -c 2;
    echo "I like " $fn $append 
done
```

EDIT

The logic that will check AND append (s) or (es)

if test last = "o"; then append = "es";
else append = "s"

EDIT 2

Need this to use if then else condition to set (s) or (es)

Comment: By what rule do you decide if you will append `(s)` or `(es)`?

Comment: @user000001 pls check the edited section of the question above

Comment: Why do you need to "use if then else condition to set (s) or (es)"? `case` **is** an "if then else" statement.

Comment: As @user000001 noted in a comment on one of the answers, "peachs" is not the plural of "peach," so you might want to revise your logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have this one which is compatible in all shells basing from System V sh. Just use case statements to be able to use glob patterns.

```
#!/bin/sh

fruitlist="apple pear tomato peach grape"

for a in $fruitlist; do
    case $a in
    *o)
        append=es
        ;;
    *)
        append=s
        ;;
    esac
    echo "${a}${append}"
done
```

Output:

```
apples
pears
tomatoes
peachs
grapes
```

Also take note how you could have the form `${var}` to be able to place variable names next to another valid variable character inside double quotes `""`. And using double quotes for quoting variables is always a good practice for starters.

It's still a suggestion that you try learning or using bash soon as POSIX shells has limits on preventing possible pathname expansion during word splitting like in `for in word; do ...; done`.

For the OP's edit # 2, this would still work with bash called through `sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

fruitlist="apple pear tomato peach grape"

for a in $fruitlist; do
    if [[ $a == *o ]]; then
        append=es
    else
        append=s
    fi
    echo "${a}${append}"
done
```

And it seems like there's another way in POSIX mode:

```
#!/bin/sh

fruitlist="apple pear tomato peach grape"

for a in $fruitlist; do
    if [ "$a" != "${a%o}" ]; then
        append=es
    else
        append=s
    fi
    echo "${a}${append}"
done
```

Comment: Oh! I always loved solutions using ``case``.

Comment: And ``echo "$a$append"`` is going to work as well, there's no strict need in ``${}``. But I prefer using ${} for readability. When it really matters is when you're trying to combine variables with text.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko Did you know that when it comes to performance, `case` beats everyone? :) And yes I actually noticed that it should have been *next to another valid variable name*.

Comment: by the way, do you have any proof for ``case`` beating other methods? Maybe some public benchmarks? This is very interesting.

Comment: `peachs` doesn't seem correct grammatically :) (I know that's what the question asks for)

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko You can do time on a loop within an case-embedded function. I did that before. And it's actually obvious knowing that `case` does it with itself and is part of a higher level syntax, whereas `[[ ]]` is still somehow semi-part of a normal command.

Comment: @user000001 Should have been `*o|*ch)` I guess :)

Comment: @konsolebox pls check the edited section of the question and tel me. EDIT 2

Comment: @mazraara Too bad you could only use `[[ ]]` for that, and it's not going work with `sh` based shells. In bash as POSIX (sh) mode is still works though. I'll try to create an update for it.

Comment: There's no ``[[ ]]`` in ``sh``. Please change shebang then.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko In bash's sh form there is. However please check my third answer which is POSIX compatible without the use of `case` statements.

Comment: @konsolebox can you tell what happens with this line ? "${a%o}" or $a == *o?

Comment: @mazraara I made an update to make it clearer. `${a%o}` removes any matching `o` in the end. So if a match is found `[ "$a" != "${a%o}" ]` would be valid, and that means value of `$a` ends in `o`. See Parameter Expansion section: here http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/shdiffs.html

Comment: @konsolebox tnx a lot. i have accepted this answer :)  a small thing i need to know. what is the meaning of this ? ans=`expr 0 \* 4 + 2`. i am confused why both division and multiplication is used in middle. \*

Comment: @mazraara It's not division. It's just a quote. It's same as `expr 0 '*' 4 + 2`. `*` after all is a glob pattern for pathname expansion so you have to quote it.

Comment: @mazraara You could see more info about pathname expansion here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html. Also more about quoting: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html

Comment: @konsolebox you means its multiplication ? i am wondering how it gives the answer as 2 for expr 0 '*' 4 + 2

Comment: @mazraara That's because in the world of programming, multiplication and division has higher precedence over addition and subtraction. You can see a table of it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages

Comment: @konsolebox my bad i dint get it. tnx again. i am done with this now. :)

Comment: @mazraara 0 * 4 + 2 = (0 * 4) + 2 = 0 + 2 = 2 :) And yes * is multplication :)

Answer (score 3):

This is in `bash`, not `sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

fruitlist=(apple pear tomato peach grape);

for curFruit in "${fruitlist[@]}"; do
    [[ ${curFruit: -1} == 'o' ]] && ending='es' || ending='s'
    echo "I like ${curFruit}$ending"
done
```

Also note that you cannot remove the space in `${curFruit: -1}`. Without space character it will become a syntax for [default value](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value).

Also, if you don't like one line if syntax, use this:

```
if [[ ${curFruit: -1} == 'o' ]]; then
    ending='es'
else
    ending='s'
fi
```

Comment: sorry i am new comer to linux side. can i pls know why do u call it as bash instead of shell.  i am able to run it with #!/bin/sh also my file is saved as .sh extension

Comment: @mazraara in linux extension doesn't mean anything. What really matters is [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). So, instead of ``#!/bin/sh`` for my solution you have to use ``#!/bin/bash``. Call your script normally like ``./myscript``

Comment: @Alex i need to call with the extension. for example ./shell1.sh

Comment: @mazraara as I already pointed out, it doesn't matter. But there's no point in ``.sh`` extension, you can safely rename your file and remove .sh ending. Or you can keep it if you really like it. Doesn't matter.

Comment: @mazraara that's because your file is probably called ``shell1.sh``. If you rename it to ``shell1`` then you can execute it like ``./shell1``. Or you can keep the the filename as ``shell1.sh`` and execute it with ``./shell1.sh``. But this does not mean that file is going to be executed by ``bash`` or ``sh``, it is just a filename, it could be anything.

Comment: @mazraara Unlike in DOS/WinX, filename extensions doesn't really matter :)

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko can you please tell how to do the same as above with using if then else rather one line logic of [[ ${curFruit: -1} == 'o' ]] && ending='es' || ending='s' pls

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko many tnx. bt can i use test command this way. if [[ ${curFruit: -1} == 'o' ]; instead if test [ ${curFruit: -1} == 'o' ]]; ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use bash, then a regex match would be what you want:

```
do
    [[ $fn =~ o|h$ ]] && append="e" || append=""
    echo "I like $fn(${append}s)"
done
```

Otherwise, if you want to stick to sh, you can use tail:

```
do
    last=$(echo -n "$fn" | tail -c 1)
    [ "$last" = o ] || [ "$last" = h ] && append="e" || append=""
    echo "I like $fn(${append}s)"
done
```

Finally, you can use expansion as [aleks suggestts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18642529/828193).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (Bash):

```
a=($fruitlist)             # put fruitlist into an array `a`
b=(${a[@]/%o/oe})          # replace words ending in `o` with `oe`
printf "%s\n" ${b[@]/%/s}  # append `s` to all words and print out
```